# To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have bound bulk records in a Kendo UI grid. The response is returned from Json.

I am getting Error while using below format:

**Problem Code : Method 1:**

```
public JsonResult KendoserverSideDemo(int pageSize, int skip=10)
{
  using (var s = new KendoEntities())
  {
    var total = s.Students.Count();

    if (total != null)
    {
      var data = s.Students.OrderBy(x=>x.StudentID).Skip(skip)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

      return Json(new { total = total, 
                        data = data,
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Method 2 : Working fine using this:**

```
public JsonResult KendoserverSideDemo(int pageSize, int skip=10)
{
  using (var s = new KendoEntities())
  {
    var total = s.Students.Count();

    if (total != null)
    {
      var data = s.Students.OrderBy(x=>x.StudentID).Skip(skip)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

      return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem in first Method 1?

Comment: Your `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is one curly brace too far to the left and will be returned in the actual JSON.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You have simple typo/syntax error

```
return Json(new { total = total, data = data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
```

The `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is the second parameter of `Json` - it shouldnt be part of the object

```
return Json(new { total = total, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen when there is same request from two different tabs in the same page. In my case, I was loading data of two same grid from two different tabs.When I closed one of the them and refreshed the page again. The error was cleared out